# iOS Core plot - align y axis labels

Tags: ios, alignment, core-plot

I want to align the y axis labels of my scatter plot in Core Plot. Currently, the labels are like this:

16

12

8

4

How can I change they alignment to right :

16

12

_8

_4

I tried the following:

```
y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentRight;
```

It didn't work. How can I do this alignment?

Edit-
Here is my code:

```
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;    
y.title = @"Y Label";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -40.0f;       
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;    
y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;    
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: That should work. Can you show more of the axis setup code?

Comment: I came across this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/l38qGhfaZgY but am unable to understand what to do exactly.

Comment: So you have labels to the right of a vertical axis and you want the labels right-aligned, leaving a variable amount of space between the tick marks and the labels?

Comment: No. I want the labels to have a constant amount of space with the axis. If we see the graph, my labels are to the left of the axis.

Comment: The label offset is -40. So thats why the labels are displayed to the left of the y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the label direction independently from the tick direction now. To have the tick marks extend to the right of the axis while lining up the labels on the left side, use the following settings:

```
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
y.tickLabelDirection = CPTSignNegative;
y.labelOffset = 5.0;
```

Comment: When I use the above code, I get the following error: Property 'tickLabelDirection' not found on object of type 'CPTAxis *'

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? That property was introduced in release 1.4.

Comment: Aaaaah! Actually it still doesn't!! It seems to align it right. But if I have values like 120.0 and below 0.0 the 120 aligns to the graph but 0.0 is on the right of the whole width of the 120's "textfield" =/